# Calculating total processor time used

Tags: linux, process

I can get how long the server has been running through `uptime`, but is there any way to get the total amount of processor time spent on all processes combined?

I can do this on my Windows desktop by subtracting the System Idle Process time from the uptime, but is there any similar method in Linux?

Comment: Yes, programmatically.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you answering your own question in the comments?

Comment: The question I was answering there was deleted, for some reason.

Comment: @coder543 I was commenting that "Programmatically? Else it sounds off-topic." But since my assertion was wrong, I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [/proc/stat](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm) file. It should contain the idle CPU numbers you're looking for, so with a little math you'll be able to calculate how long the CPU has been idle.

EDIT:
Also, here's an example of how to get the percentage from any Linux terminal:

```
head -n 1 /proc/stat | awk '{ print "\n"; printf (($2+$3+$4+$7+$8+$9)/($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9))*100; print "% of the time since the computer was booted has been spent doing work." }'
```

I think I've got it handling all of the columns correctly there.

Comment: So if I understand right, I take the sum of all columns except idle, divide by the sum of all columns (including idle), and I get the ratio of time spent working?

Comment: Yes, except that you should bundle `iowait` in with `idle`, since `iowait` simply means "waiting on I/O" (and therefore not doing any work).

Comment: I added an example of how to do it from the Linux shell, the command runs off the edge of the box though, so make sure to copy it all.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very helpful. I see the file also contains the boot time, so I can calculate the actual amount of time too.